# Select Distinct row in Laravel Eloquent

Tags: laravel

I am using Laravel 8. I have two tables album and images, Images belongs to an album. I want just to display images but the ones with distinct album_id. I am trying to achieve it without success.

```
 public function index(){
   $images=albumImages::distinct('album_id')->pluck('album_id','path');
    dd($images);
    return view('gallery',compact('images'));
   }
```

This is the output

[image]

Comment: `albumImages::distinct('album_id')` -- i cant find `distinct` function with parameter. what is `albumImages`? is the `distinct` a function you added?

Comment: That is a table that belongs to album  but with images

Comment: you meant an eloquent model?

Comment: yes it is an eloquent model. and contains album_id and path

Comment: again, i'm not aware `distinct` with parameter (see [the docs](https://laravel.com/api/9.x/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.html#method_distinct)). but if your `albumImages` has a relation from `album`, you can use constrained eager loading to get `album`s accompanied by one `albumImage` each. something like `album::with(['images' => function($q){ return $q->first(); }])` should work assuming `album` has relationship named `images` for `albumImages`.

Comment: You need to `select('album_id','path')` so `distinct` work on the columns

Comment: You have multiple paths per album id, which specific one do you want to keep?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve?  You need just one image from each album, but you don't care which one?

Comment: @snapey I am trying to create a gallary, I want one image to be displayed for each album . when you click on that image you can now view the rest.

Comment: If using a recent version of Laravel, you can create a relationship 'firstOfMany' which could return one record from each gallery